# Correct approach using Collections with GridView control asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my typical scenario:

I have many c# business objects that more or less match my database design. I also have collections of these objects that I use to bind to gridviews. What is the best way to combine fields from both of these objects to my gridview (without using datatables or creating a view)

Let's say I want a gridview with the following columns: Product ID, Product Name, Product Cost, Shipping Company Name. Usually I simply get my collection of products from the database and use an item template for the shipping company name. I would then get the ShippingCompanyID in the rowdatabound event and go to the database again to get my shipping company name. I hate going to the database twice, can someone coach me on how I should approach this?

Product Class

- ProductID
- Name
- Cost
- ShippingCompanyID

Shipping Company Class

- ShippingCompanyID
- Name

Answer (score 1):

You may use joins in `Linq`  to achieve the desire result.

```
 var result = from prd in products
         from cmp in companies
         where prd.ShippingCompanyID == cmp.ShippingCompanyID
         select new
          {
            ProductID=prd.ProductID,
            ProductName=prd.Name,
            Company=cmp.Name 
         };
```

Comment: Thanks AVD! Would you actually approach this type of problem this way? Do you prefer working with datatables instead of collections? Is there a speed issue using linq to combine the collections instead of joining the table once in the database instead of in the code? Also, this way forces you to go to the database twice, once for the products, again for the companies.

Comment: @stillsmallvoice - I prefer joining the table in database by creating views or stored-proc.

Answer (score 1):

using LINQ, assuming `products` is a collection of type `Product`, and `shippingCompanies` is a collection of type `ShippingCompany`.

```
from p in products
join s in shippingCompanies on p.ShippingCompanyID equals s.ShippingCompanyID
select new { p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Cost, s.Name }
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, we actually include the company name in the class that is bound to the grid (Products) and join the tables in the database, usually in a view.

This way there is no extra work in code and that same view can be re-used in other scenarios, such as report generation.